# Trigonometry : verify that $\cos \frac{A}{2} +\cos 2A = 0$ for $A=\frac{2\pi}{5}$

Tags: trigonometry

Question in trigonometry: verify that $\cos\frac{A}{2} + \cos 2A = 0$.

Let $A = \frac{2\pi}{5}$.

1. Verify that $\cos \frac{A}{2} + \cos 2A = 0$.
2. Show that $x=\cos A$ satisifies the equation $x=2(4x^4-4x^2+1)-1$.
3. Factor $8x^4-8x^2-x+1$ over $\mathbb Z$, and deduce that $\cos A$ is a zero of a quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb Z$.
4. Determine $\cos A.$

My solution is as follows :
We know $\cos(A/2)=\sqrt{(1+\cos A)/2}$ 
and $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1$.

$\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1$

It is sufficient if we prove that $\cos2A=-\cos(A/2)$   for the first question.

$2\cos^2A-1=\pm\sqrt{(1+\cos A)/2}$

squaring on both sides and simplifying:
$8\cos4A+2-8\cos^2A=1+\cos A$

subsitituting $\cos A$ with $x$ :

$8x^4- 8x^2+2-1 = x$

$2(4x^4-4x^2+1)-1=x$

I believe that if I do the same thing backwards, I will get the answer for question (2)

I have factorized the equation and ended up with this:
$(x-1)[8x^3+8x-1]$
Now, the third question asks me to deduce that cosA is a zero of quadratic polynomial, but I have only linear and cubic factors, how do I proceed?

Regarding the first question, I’m clueless, I have simplified it as much as possible, but its not going anywhere.

Comment: Is it $\frac{\cos A}2$ or $\cos \frac A2$?

Comment: No, this is not the way we do things here. You don't just copy-paste something you don't understand with bad formatting and no source and no indication that you have done any work on it. Please try again.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Sorry for the bad formatting, I have infact solved a great portion of it, and I'll type that up aswell..

Comment: What you have done should be part of your initial posting of the question, so no one wastes her time and yours telling you things you already know.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Okay, I get it, why be so impolite?

Comment: I don't know. Why be so impolite as to post a question here with no indication of where it came from, and without letting people in on the work you had done on it? In any event, I'm glad to see that you have improved the question greatly. You might have a look at the edits some of us have done, to get some idea of how best to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

$1$.

$\cos \frac A2=\cos \frac \pi5$ and

as $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x,$ 
$\cos2A=\cos\frac{4\pi}5=\cos\left(\pi-\frac\pi5\right)=-\cos\frac\pi5 $

$2$.

As $5A=2\pi,A=2\pi-4A$

So using $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$ and $\cos(2\pi-x)=\cos x$,

$\cos A=\cos(2\pi-4A)=\cos 4A=2(\cos2A)^2-1=2(2\cos^2A-1)^2-1=8\cos^4A-8\cos^2A+1$

$3$.

But $\cos4A=\cos A$

$\implies 4A=2n\pi\pm A$ where $n$ is any integer

Taking $'+'$ sign, $A=\frac{2n\pi}5$ where $n=0,1,2,3,4$

So, the roots are $\cos0=1,$
$\cos\frac{2\pi}5, \cos\frac{4\pi}5=\cos\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}5\right)=-\cos\frac\pi5<0,$
$\cos\frac{6\pi}5=\cos\left(\pi+\frac{\pi}5\right)=-\cos\frac\pi5,$
$\cos\frac{8\pi}5=\cos\left(2\pi-\frac{8\pi}5\right)=\cos\frac{2\pi}5$

Taking $'-'$ sign, $A=\frac{2n\pi}3$ where $n=0,1,2$

So, the roots are $\cos0=1,$
$\cos\frac{2\pi}3=\cos\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}3\right)=-\cos\frac\pi3=-\frac12,$
$\cos\frac{4\pi}3=\cos\left(\pi+\frac{\pi}3\right)=-\cos\frac\pi3=-\frac12,$

So, $8x^4-8x^2-x+1=(x-1)\{x-(-\frac12)\}\left(x-\cos\frac{2\pi}5\right)\{x-(-\cos\frac{\pi}5)\}$

So, $\cos\frac{2\pi}5>0,-\cos\frac{\pi}5<0$ are the roots of the qaudratic eqaution $$\frac{8x^4-8x^2-x+1}{(x-1)(x+\frac12)}=0\ \ \ \ (1)$$

$4$.

As $A=\frac{2\pi}5,0<\frac{2\pi}5<\frac\pi2,$ the value of $\cos\frac{2\pi}5$ will be the positive root of $(1)$

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution of the first part.

Comment: @Niharika, my pleasure. Please find the edited version. By trial & error, we can divide your cube by $2x+1$ to reach at the required Quadratic Eqaution.

Comment: Thankyou very much.  I was really stuck up with getting a Quadratic. Do you think there is any other efficient way to come up with the quadratic rather than trial and error?

Comment: @Niharika, I've used Trial & Error :). Have you heard of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method